# RabbitMQ Management Plugin Web Server

Tags: rabbitmq

I've installed a RabbitMQ cluster on EC2 nodes. The cluster is up and running. I'm trying to get the rabbitmq_management plugin running. I installed the rabbitmq_management plugin on all cluster nodes.

RabbitMQ V 3.02, Ubuntu server 12.04

Plugins enabled:

```
[e] amqp_client                       3.0.2
[e] mochiweb                          2.3.1-rmq3.0.2-gitd541e9a
[E] rabbitmq_management               3.0.2
[e] rabbitmq_management_agent         3.0.2
[e] rabbitmq_mochiweb                 3.0.2
[e] webmachine                        1.9.1-rmq3.0.2-git52e62bc
```

After restarting rabbitmq_server, running applications:

```
{running_applications,[{rabbit,"RabbitMQ","3.0.2"},
                        {os_mon,"CPO  CXC 138 46","2.2.7"},
                        {mnesia,"MNESIA  CXC 138 12","4.5"},
                        {sasl,"SASL  CXC 138 11","2.1.10"},
                        {stdlib,"ERTS  CXC 138 10","1.17.5"},
                        {kernel,"ERTS  CXC 138 10","2.14.5"}]},
```

`http://hostname:15672` does not load (the port is open in the EC2 security group).

It appears that the web server is not running. I restarted the service after installing the management plugin, and do not see any errors in startup_log. startup_err is empty.

Suggestions on where to go from here?

UPDATE:

Rebooting the nodes entirely worked. So presumably there was something I did not shut down properly before restarting the first time.

Any insight would still be welcome.

Comment: I'm currently having the same problem, any suggestions on how I can fix this? Reboot the instance perhaps?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Should have answered this long ago, I found this to properly stop and restart Rabbit.

```
sudo rabbitmqctl stop
sudo invoke-rc.d rabbitmq-server start
```

Comment: Unless it states further in the documents, I didn't see a restart required for the plugin to work. However, I had to use the stop/start from your answer, and now it's loading. You can accept your own answer.

Comment: Two things - a restart of RabbitMQ should not be necessary, and you are using an **ancient** version of RabbitMQ. Please be sure to run the recommended versions of Erlang and RabbitMQ to avoid issues going forward!!!